# Как вводить в список сразу несколько числовых значений?

Tags: python

Цель: сделать так, чтобы **пользователь вводил** (уже после запуска кода) в **список** сразу **несколько** **числовых** значений, и при этом, чтобы они все были в формате чисел (int, как я понимаю), а не str.

Пытался сделать через такой код:

```
list=[int(input('Введите числа, из которых будет состоять список: '))]
print(list)
```

Но он работает только тогда, когда я ввожу лишь одно число, а мне нужно вводить сразу несколько. Когда я пытаюсь ввести несколько чисел мне пишет:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3' - это числа, которые я пытаюсь ввести. Не важно, есть междуними запятая, или нет, всё равно ошибка :(
```

Помогите написать корректный код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый примитивный способ при условии, что все вводимые данные будут числами:

```
list_data = [int(value) for value in input().split()]
print(list_data)
```

Пояснение:

1. вводите числа через пробел.
2. **.split()** - вернет список элементов, разделенных пробелом
3. при помощи генератора вы пробегаетесь по каждому элементу и интуете их.
4. Результат ложится в переменную **list_data**, где все числа будут интовыми

ЛИБО по сложнее, но с проверкой:

```
list_data = input().split()
int_lst = []
for element in list_data:
    if element.isdigit():
        int_lst.append(int(element))
    else:
        print(f'{element} - не является числом! ')
        print('Ошибка формирования списка чисел!')
        exit()
print(f'Ваш список чисел:', int_lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нам нужна функция `split`, которая разделяет введенную строку по пробелу (или по другому символу, но параметр по умолчанию - это пробел).

```
lst = input().split()
```

Но в таком случае введенные числа будут храниться, как строки.
Чтобы преобразовать их в тип `int`, мы можем либо использовать генератор списков:

```
lst = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Либо функцию `map`, которая применяет определенную функцию (в нашем случае `int`) ко всем элементам списка:

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(list(map(int, input('Введите числа, из которых будет состоять список: \n').split())))
```